# efficient Schwartz-Bayes matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, autoregressive-models

N00B question, but what is a more efficient way of doing this?
I'm just trying to calculate test statistics for all 36 permutations of parameters in the model.

```
ARIMAP0Q<-c(BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(0,0,0))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(1,0,0))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(2,0,0))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(3,0,0))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(4,0,0))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(5,0,0))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(0,0,1))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(1,0,1))),
            BIC(arima(italy.1$gap,order=c(2,0,1))),
```

it feel really stupid doing it like this

Comment: your possible orders are 0:5, 0:3, 0:2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expand.grid` to get all the possible orders.

Then use `apply` to your heart's content.

```
ARIMAP0Q <- apply(expand.grid(0:5, 0:2, 0:3), 1L,
                  function(rw) BIC(arima(italy.1$gap, order = rw)))
```

Comment: @slap-a-da-bias have `sapply` / `lapply` / `apply` in mind any time you are doing something repetitive and you'll rarely go wrong.

Comment: also definitely peruse this excellent Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega